# Deeplinking in killed state. iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a problem with deep linking.
When app is not running my app will load the url in this function and that works. But after that a other view will get over it because it will start the app. I can't figure out where the problem lies. I use MvvmCross so my application class will also start a ViewModel and that view will get over it.
Is there any solution that can prevent my application class to load or that openURL will be called after that.

This is the function that loads the url:

```
public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        if (userActivity.ActivityType == "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb")
        {
            OpenUrl(userActivity.WebPageUrl.Path);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

If anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide more codes to reproduce your problem?I think your app will start firstly and then load the url.

Comment: I don't think so. It look it opens first the url and then the app. I use mvvm cross. First the ContinueUserActivity is called and then de DidFinishedLaunch. But that will also opens a page on top of the openURL.